# How to save StringArray from ImageAdapter in SQLite

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I am able to delete images from RecyclerView but I am doing it from `ImageAdapter` and works perfectly. But After deletion of image, I am getting file names from the remaining images and saving it into a single string to save it in the SQLite. But the problem is that I am saving data into database in the fragment activity and not from `ImageAdapter`. How can i save this `String` file in the database with `backpress` button?

My `imageAdapter`

```
   bpAdapter.remove(currentPosition);
                    z.delete();
                    ImageFileArrayAfterDelete.remove(currentPosition);
                    toSingleString();
                    notifyItemRemoved(currentPosition);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(currentPosition, bpAdapter.size());
                    Integer arrayLength = (Integer) ImageFileArrayAfterDelete.size();
                    Log.d("TAG_", "After Delete image size and name: " + arrayLength);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete)
            .show();
}
private void toSingleString(){
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < ImageFileArrayAfterDelete.size(); i++) {
        result.append( ImageFileArrayAfterDelete.get(i));
        result.append( ",");
    }
    stringForArray = result.toString();
```

And here is my fragment where i am saving the text, title and string of images

```
public void save() {    
String almostSameText = Html.toHtml(texto.getEditableText()).toString();
                        if (bp != null) {
                            Util.saveToInternalStorage(context, bp, ArrayImageName, photos);
                            base.modificarNota(titulo.getText().toString().trim(), almostSameText, stringForArray, id);
                         }
                        else {
                            base.modificarNota(titulo.getText().toString().trim(), almostSameText, null, id);
                        }
                            getActivity().onBackPressed();
                            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_left,R.anim.exit_from_right);
                    }
```

Comment: You should look into how to use gson library, it will turn a list into a string and back into a list.

Comment: I just want to save the string file in the sqlite with backpress button but the problem is that my activity cannot access to save method and for that i have to make everything public static

Comment: What are you calling back pressed from mainavtivity?

Comment: i want to call save method

Comment: According to Android Docs, you should be saving it in the onPause function of your Activity.